# What're all the LLVM layers for?

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-c++-api

I'm playing with LLVM `3.7` and wanted to use the new ORC stuff. But I've been going at this for a few hours now and still don't get what the each layer is for, when to use them, how to compose them or at the very least the minimum set of things I need in place.

Been through the `Kaleidoscope` tutorial but these don't explain what the constituent parts are, just says put this here and this here (plus the parsing etc distracts from the core LLVM bits). While that's great to get started it leaves a lot of gaps. There are lots of docs on various things in LLVM but there's so much its actually bordering on overwhelming. Stuff like http://llvm.org/releases/3.7.0/docs/ProgrammersManual.html but I can't find anything that explains how all the pieces fit together. Even more confusing there seems to be multiple APIs for doing the same thing, thinking of the `MCJIT` and the newer `ORC` API. I saw [Lang Hames post](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.compilers.llvm.devel/80639) explaining, a fair few things seem to have changed since the patch he posted in that link.

So for a specific question, how do all these layers fit together?
When I previously used LLVM I could link to C functions fairly easily, using the "[How to use JIT](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/examples/HowToUseJIT/HowToUseJIT.cpp)" example as a base, I tried linking to an externed function `extern "C" double doIt` but end up with `LLVM ERROR: Tried to execute an unknown external function: doIt`.

Having a look at [this ORC](https://github.com/chapuni/llvm/blob/7368f2145aff1c1f9faa24c307b3fe29b94d184c/tools/lli/OrcLazyJIT.h#L90-L102) example it seems I need to configure where it searches for the symbols. But TBH while I'm still swinging at this, its largely guess work. Here's what I got:

```
#include "llvm/ADT/STLExtras.h"
#include "llvm/ExecutionEngine/GenericValue.h"
#include "llvm/ExecutionEngine/Interpreter.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Constants.h"
#include "llvm/IR/DerivedTypes.h"
#include "llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Instructions.h"
#include "llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Module.h"
#include "llvm/Support/ManagedStatic.h"
#include "llvm/Support/TargetSelect.h"
#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"
#include "std.hpp"

using namespace llvm;

int main() {

  InitializeNativeTarget();

  LLVMContext Context;

  // Create some module to put our function into it.
  std::unique_ptr<Module> Owner = make_unique<Module>("test", Context);
  Module *M = Owner.get();

  // Create the add1 function entry and insert this entry into module M.  The
  // function will have a return type of "int" and take an argument of "int".
  // The '0' terminates the list of argument types.
  Function *Add1F = cast<Function>(M->getOrInsertFunction("add1", Type::getInt32Ty(Context), Type::getInt32Ty(Context), (Type *) 0));

  // Add a basic block to the function. As before, it automatically inserts
  // because of the last argument.
  BasicBlock *BB = BasicBlock::Create(Context, "EntryBlock", Add1F);

  // Create a basic block builder with default parameters.  The builder will
  // automatically append instructions to the basic block `BB'.
  IRBuilder<> builder(BB);

  // Get pointers to the constant `1'.
  Value *One = builder.getInt32(1);

  // Get pointers to the integer argument of the add1 function...
  assert(Add1F->arg_begin() != Add1F->arg_end()); // Make sure there's an arg
  Argument *ArgX = Add1F->arg_begin();  // Get the arg
  ArgX->setName("AnArg");            // Give it a nice symbolic name for fun.

  // Create the add instruction, inserting it into the end of BB.
  Value *Add = builder.CreateAdd(One, ArgX);

  // Create the return instruction and add it to the basic block
  builder.CreateRet(Add);

  // Now, function add1 is ready.


  // Now we're going to create function `foo', which returns an int and takes no
  // arguments.
  Function *FooF = cast<Function>(M->getOrInsertFunction("foo", Type::getInt32Ty(Context), (Type *) 0));

  // Add a basic block to the FooF function.
  BB = BasicBlock::Create(Context, "EntryBlock", FooF);

  // Tell the basic block builder to attach itself to the new basic block
  builder.SetInsertPoint(BB);

  // Get pointer to the constant `10'.
  Value *Ten = builder.getInt32(10);

  // Pass Ten to the call to Add1F
  CallInst *Add1CallRes = builder.CreateCall(Add1F, Ten);
  Add1CallRes->setTailCall(true);

  // Create the return instruction and add it to the basic block.
  builder.CreateRet(Add1CallRes);

  std::vector<Type *> args;
  args.push_back(Type::getDoubleTy(getGlobalContext()));
  FunctionType *FT = FunctionType::get(Type::getDoubleTy(getGlobalContext()), args, false);

  Function *F = Function::Create(FT, Function::ExternalLinkage, "doIt", Owner.get());

  // Now we create the JIT.
  ExecutionEngine *EE = EngineBuilder(std::move(Owner)).create();

  outs() << "We just constructed this LLVM module:\n\n" << *M;
  outs() << "\n\nRunning foo: ";
  outs().flush();

  // Call the `foo' function with no arguments:
  std::vector<GenericValue> noargs;
  GenericValue gv = EE->runFunction(FooF, noargs);
  auto ax = EE->runFunction(F, noargs);

  // Import result of execution:
  outs() << "Result: " << gv.IntVal << "\n";
  outs() << "Result 2: " << ax.IntVal << "\n";
  delete EE;
  llvm_shutdown();
  return 0;
}
```

`doIt` is declared in `std.hpp`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is very vague, but maybe I can help a bit. [This code sample](https://github.com/eliben/llvm-clang-samples/blob/master/src_llvm/jit_orc_run.cpp) is a simple JIT built with Orc - it's well commented so it should be easy to follow.

Put simply, Orc builds on top of the same building blocks used by MCJIT (MC for compiling LLVM modules down to object files, `RuntimeDyld` for the dynamic linking at runtime), but provides more flexibility with its concept of layers. It can thus support things like "lazy" JIT compilation, which MCJIT doesn't support. This is important for the LLVM community because the "old JIT" that was removed not very long ago supported these things. Orc JIT lets us gain back these advanced JIT capabilities while still building on top of MC and thus not duplicating the code emission logic.

To get better answers, I suggest you ask more specific questions.

Comment: Thanks, that code sample is helpful. The vagueness of my question stems from my lack of understanding I think. Having spent the weekend on this I think I'm starting to get it so hopefully if I have any questions going forward they'll be very specific.